# What is the easiest and safest sailboat type and size for cruising and ocean crossing for a crew of two?

Tags: sailing

I am researching the type and size of sailboat that would allow me and my wife to, one day, cruise and cross the ocean.  I saw many different boat and sail types.

What would be the sailboat keel type and mast configuration (schooner, sloop, ketch, etc) that would provide the safest and easiest operation?

For size, is a 40 footer a minimum?

I am looking for answers from people who had crossed an ocean passage with a sailboat to provide a summary of tips like:

1. Years of sailboat experience before they attempt this
2. The boat, size, type and anything that made the trip safer and easier for them
3. Optional - What was the passage route?  time of year to travel.

Comment: How much experience do you have, which oceans and which time of year? You will need to narrow down the question a lot otherwise it is impossible to answer. And unless you have a lot of experience I would not want to answer, (as sailing oceans is often cause of death.)

Comment: If you're looking to go deep water sailing you might start out with a ketch and try something like the inland waterway first.

Comment: This would be much better answered by our [Great Outdoors site](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com) which has questions about sailing. Although it may need to be made more specific.

Comment: I would say that if you need to ask this you should not try to attempt the travel. People get sailing experience by manning first smaller boats on shorter, close to the shore travels in perfect weather and then continue on more complicate setups. Once you have enough experience to take on a travel of this type, you will already need which vessel you will need and which aspects are important (for example, you do not mention the space needed to store food and water for the travel...)

Comment: Sailing across an **ocean** is NOT a vacation.  You will encounter really bad weather and there is a massive risk of dying out there.  If you want to go across the ocean in a leisurely manner, get on a cruise ship.

Comment: I would love to hear from people who had actual experiences of crossing oceans with a simple summary as:
1.  Had 5 years sail boat experience with 5000 nautical miles coastal cruising
2.  Used a 36' sloop or whatever
3.  Any other tips.

Comment: @JamesNW Up-voted. This question is only "unclear" to people who know nothing about the topic. That said, I cannot provide an answer because it's already been closed.


I would suggest instead creating an account over at www.cruisersforum.com. I would be glad to answer your question over there, as would many other members.

Comment: Ask on The Great Outdoors site,degree this will be on topic.